# Is there a way of this query working with JOINs or must I use a UNION?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am probably trying to use JOINs for purposes they were not intended here.

Here's my (simplified) table structure:

Table A

- ID
- Table C ID
- IsStatic (bit)

Table B

- ID
- Table A ID (nullable)
- Table C ID

Table C

- ID

My goal is to get all of Table B rows joined to Table A rows where Table B's Table A ID column has a value and equals Table A's ID column value.

I also need all of Table B rows where Table B's Table A ID column has no value.

I also need all of Table A rows with there were no joined Table B rows and Table A's IsStatic column is true.

Table C must also be associated with Table A or Table B. If Table B does not have a value for TableAID then it's value for TableCID should equal TableC's ID value. Otherwise TableA's TableCID should equal TableC's ID value.

Here's some SQL to create some TABLE variables and populate with sample data:

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (TableAID int, TableCID int, IsStatic bit)
DECLARE @TableB TABLE (TableBID int, TableAID int, TableCID int)
DECLARE @TableC TABLE (TableCID int)

INSERT INTO @TableC (TableCID) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO @TableC (TableCID) VALUES (2)

INSERT INTO @TableA (TableAID, TableCID, IsStatic) VALUES (1, 1, 0)
INSERT INTO @TableA (TableAID, TableCID, IsStatic) VALUES (2, 2, 1)
INSERT INTO @TableA (TableAID, TableCID, IsStatic) VALUES (3, 2, 1)
INSERT INTO @TableA (TableAID, TableCID, IsStatic) VALUES (4, 2, 0)

INSERT INTO @TableB (TableBID, TableAID, TableCID) VALUES (1, NULL, 1)
INSERT INTO @TableB (TableBID, TableAID, TableCID) VALUES (2, 1, 1)
INSERT INTO @TableB (TableBID, TableAID, TableCID) VALUES (3, 2, 2)
```

Here's my (simplified) query that didn't quite work:

```
SELECT
    a.TableAID,
    b.TableBID
FROM @TableC c
LEFT OUTER JOIN @TableB b ON
    (b.TableAID IS NOT NULL OR (b.TableAID IS NULL AND b.TableCID = c.TableCID))
LEFT OUTER JOIN @TableA a ON
    a.TableCID = c.TableCID
    AND ((a.IsStatic = 1 AND b.TableBID IS NULL)
        OR (b.TableBID IS NOT NULL AND b.TableAID = a.TableAID))
```

The result of this query using the sampel data is:

```
TableAID TableBID
-----------------
NULL     1
1        2
NULL     3       (not required)
NULL     2       (not required)
2        3
```

The required result is:

```
TableAID TableBID
-----------------
NULL     1
3        NULL     (missing)
2        3
1        2
```

Problem with this query is that if TableB.TableAID has no value then the Table A rows where TableA.IsStatic is true without any matching TableB rows are never included. Also some TableB rows are being included and they shouldn't be.

The only other way I can see of doing this is with a `union` with a `not exists` but I was hoping to do this in a more efficient way.

**Update:** Adding a WHERE clause removes the "not required" rows but still omits the missing row.

```
WHERE (b.TableBID IS NULL OR b.TableAID IS NULL OR b.TableAID = a.TableAID)
```

The result of the same query with the where clause is:

```
TableAID TableBID
-----------------
NULL     1
1        2
2        3
```

Comment: In your joins try this instead. JOIN table ON ISNULL(table.column,'') = ISNULL(otherTable.column,''). Forgive my formatting. I'm on my mobile.

Comment: Joins are for combining columns into a single row. You are trying to combine rows together into a single result set. That is what unions are for. Your query will be easier to maintain and understand if you just use a union. Is there some reason you're trying to avoid it?

Comment: @MikeD. - fear of commitment! (joking... union, get it?) Seriously, I thought I would have to have an inefficient `not exists` in the query which I wanted to avoid. But Anton's answer avoids this and I'm just seeing if that will work for me.

Comment: johna, the answer is already provided, please review it and mark as accepted if it is what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a mind twister. I think that this is another way to express it. You'll have to see if the performance is good or not:

```
select a.TableAID, b.TableBID
  from (select a.*
          from @TableA a
          join @TableC c
            on c.TableCID = a.TableCID) a
  full outer join (select b.*
                     from @TableB b
                     join @TableC c
                       on c.TableCID = b.TableCID) b
    on b.TableAID = a.TableAID
 where b.TableBID is not null or a.IsStatic = 1
```

I should also mention that it's hard to know for sure if the above query really respects your requirements using the sample data you provided. To illustrate, if I use this simplified query below that simply ignores the `@TableC` table, I still get the right results with your sample data:

```
 select a.TableAID, b.TableBID
  from @TableA a
  full outer join @TableB b
    on b.TableAID = a.TableAID
 where b.TableBID is not null or a.IsStatic = 1
```

**EDIT**: Funny discussion in the comments about the interpretation of OP' requirements... But if I had to address Anton's point:

```
select a.TableAID, b.TableBID
  from (select a.*, 
               case when c.TableCID is not null then 1 end as has_c
          from @TableA a
          left join @TableC c
            on c.TableCID = a.TableCID) a
  full outer join (select b.*,
                          case when c.TableCID is not null then 1 end as has_c
                     from @TableB b
                     left join @TableC c
                       on c.TableCID = b.TableCID) b
    on b.TableAID = a.TableAID
 where (b.TableBID is not null or a.IsStatic = 1)
   and (a.has_c = 1 or b.has_c = 1)
```

Comment: It seems this script is incorrect if we change the sample data. Try to replace INSERTs for TableB VALUES (2, 1, 1) with VALUES (2, 1, 3)

Comment: You miss to display (1, 2)

Comment: @Anton, (2, 1, 3) is not valid as Table3 does not have a sample row ID value of 3. (1, 2) is showing for me.

Comment: See the requirement. If there is corresponded record in Table A, TableB's CID should not be used.  Only Table A's C ID

Comment: @john, there is no requirement to have foreign key constraint, so formally 3 is valid and can be present in Table B. As per your requirement, we should show (1, 2) if we have (3), because Table A still has valid link with Table C

Comment: That's @Anton's point. Can `@TableB` have an invalid `TableCID` value or be null?  And if so, should the row be returned anyways if a join is possible to `@TableA` and it, in turn, has a valid join to `@TableC`?  Anton, did I understand what you are saying correctly?

Comment: Also the cost of my query in the execution plan is slightly better. However, it should be checked against actual database.

Comment: sstan, yes, that's correct understanding. According to description, we must use Table A reference to C if Table A and B are linked, so my script covers that case.

Comment: Also keep in mind it's likely the query is going to use any other data in Table C.  So if you join to incorrect row in Table C, you would get incorrect data

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The sample data in my question wasn't quite right as the TableB rows which had a TableAID should have had NULL for TableCID. Apologies for the mind twisting explanation of my requirements... Naming the tables A/B/C probably made things a lot more complicated - it certainly isn't helping me as I try and test your answer and Anton's answer with my real world structure, which I have been trying to do for the last hour or two. Thanks for the great answers!

Comment: This answer worked perfectly with my real data structure and data and was the most efficient for me. Thank you very much! Note that I used the pre-edit version (top one) but left out the two inner joins to TableC and replaced them (`LEFT OUTER JOIN @TableC c ON c.TableCID = CASE WHEN a.TableAId IS NOT NULL THEN a.TableCID ELSE b.TableCID END`).

Answer (score 4):

```
select b.TableAID, b.TableBID
from @TableB b
    left join @TableA a on a.TableAID = b.TableAID
    inner join @TableC c on c.TableCID = case when a.TableAID IS NULL then b.TableCID else a.TableCID end

union all

select a.TableAID, NULL
from @TableA a
    inner join @TableC c on c.TableCID = a.TableCID
    left join @TableB b on b.TableAID = a.TableAID
where b.TableAID is NULL
    and a.IsStatic = 1
```

Comment: This answer works really well. However I accepted @sstan's answer as the execution plan and speed was better (more due to the real data structure and indexing). Thank you very much for the answer and I can confirm that it worked perfectly with the real structure and data.